# Lua table filtering ip's

Tags: lua

I've read a hosts file and firewall log to a table and filtered out the ipv4/6 and local
hosts redirects, I'm a bit stuck now with processing the ipv4/6 entries, I'm not looking
for the code more the method to achieve what I want, this is an example of an ipv4 table:

> ```
>    test={} 
>    test[1]="170.83.210.219 www.test.com www.test.net"
>    test[2]="170.83.210.219 www.test.co.uk"
>    test[3]="170.83.210.219 test.org"
>    test[4]="170.83.210.219 www.test.com"
>    test[5]="170.83.300.219 170.83.300.812"
>    test[6]="170.83.300.219 www.test1.co.uk"
>    test[7]="170.83.300.219 test1.org"
>    test[8]="170.83.300.219 www.test1.co.uk"
> ```

the desired output would be this iterated from a new table:

> ```
>    170.83.210.219 www.test.com www.test.net www.test.co.uk test.org  
>    170.83.300.219 170.83.300.812 test1.org www.test1.co.uk
> ```

so the script has recognized there is only 2 different Ips and its put only the
corresponding entries on the string/table if its not already there, this is where
I'm up to:

> ```
>        for i,v in pairs(test) do
>         local t2 = {}
>         for X in string.gfind (v, "[^ ]+") do
>          table.insert (t2, X) --splits the table values to a table
>         end
>         local mainip = table.concat(t2, "", 1, 1); 
>         ------brain dead!
>        end
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To eliminate duplicate IPs *and* duplicate hosts, have a table where IP addresses are the keys, and the values are subtables with hosts as the keys.

```
ips = {}
for _,line in pairs(test) do
    local ip, host = line:match('(%S+)%s+(%S+)')
    if not ips[ip] then ips[ip] = {} end
    ips[ip][host] = true
end
```

You end up with a table like this:

```
ips = {
  ['170.83.210.219'] = {
    ['www.test.com']   = true,
    ['test.org']       = true,
    ['www.test.co.uk'] = true,
  },
  ['170.83.300.219'] = {
    ['test1.org']       = true,
    ['www.test1.co.uk'] = true,
    ['170.83.300.812']  = true,
  },
}
```

Which looks weird -- you might prefer to have the host lists as arrays (i.e. 1-N as keys, with hosts as values rather than keys) -- but storing the hosts as keys is a very efficient way of eliminating duplicates.

It just means instead of iterating hosts like `for _,ip in pairs(ips[x])`, you iterate like `for ip,_ in pairs(ips[x])`.

---

If you want the result table in the `t[ip] = "host [host ...]"` format you mentioned in your OP, you could modify the routine to store each host as a key (for duplicate prevention) *and* an array element (for processing the list into a space-separated string). Then after one pass through the data to collapse any duplicates, you take another pass to create the host strings:

```
ips = {}
for i,v in pairs(test) do
    local ip, host = v:match('(%S+)%s+(%S+)')
    if not ips[ip] then ips[ip] = {} end
    if not ips[ip][host] then 
        ips[ip][host] = true -- this is duplicate prevention
        table.insert(ips[ip], host) -- this is for our concatenation later
    end
end

for ip,hosts in pairs(ips) do
    ips[ip] = table.concat(hosts, ' ')
end
```

The result of *that* is a table that looks like:

```
ips = {
  ["170.83.210.219"] = "www.test.com www.test.co.uk test.org",
  ["170.83.300.219"] = "170.83.300.812 www.test1.co.uk test1.org",
}
```

---

**SIDE NOTE:** `t={'a','b'}` produces the same table as `t={} t[1]='a' t[2] = b`.